# Unable to get parent when bottomsheet called from fragment

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm trying to set a peek height for my bottomsheet and I'm using this method below, it works fine when the BottomModalLayout is called from an activity but it doesnt when called from a fragment
Here is my code for bottomModalLayout

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Details: "+view.getParent());
    //CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) view.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior=BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
    //BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior=params.getBehavior();
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(1877);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(1877);
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

this is called from a fragement

```
analysis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BottomModalLayout bottomSheet = new BottomModalLayout();

                bottomSheet.setCancelable(false);
                bottomSheet.show(getFragmentManager(),
                        "ModalBottomSheet");
            }
        });
```

but getting this error
[image]

Kindly Help!!!
and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try that in *onStart()* callback instead

Comment: Im getting issue on this line
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior=BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());

Answer (score 0):

When you want to deal with fragment you have to take into consideration the root.
By getting the root you can do any things in the fragment.

I think the error message is because you didn’t get the root.(the null because there’s no root found)

Try to use this in order to solve the problem:

```
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(getView().findViewById(R.id.parent_view_id));
```

The `getView()` method will help you to do so or you can use:

```
View rootView = getView();
// use the rootView in your code
```

I hope I explain the point correctly.

> If you can show more of your code maybe I can help you more

Comment: Tried this but now I'm getting an issue
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @ShekharJ.Lobo Please show more information about your classes so that I can give you the suitable solution